# Can we call a c++ dll in silverlight out of browser application

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi can any one tell how can we call dlls written in c++/vc++ in out of browser application in silver light. If possible can any give the link to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doable in Silverlight 3 or earlier.

Silverlight 4 "out of browser" should be able to access COM objects on the host, so you could wrap your DLL in a COM object and use from a Silverlight.